# Edit file name with vim

Tags: vim, explorer

Is there a way to edit file names with vim using Explorer or NERDtree?

Comment: Question for SuperUser, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

vim your_directory_name

JK to move to your target directory

Shift+R to rename the directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate throw the NERDTree when you have the repertory your file should be, just press M, the Filesystem Menu should appear and you will be able to modify. its been a long time so I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard 'netrw' file explorer then put the cursor on the filename and press R.